# Displaying raster images using Leaflet?

Tags: raster, leaflet

The purpose is to create a small web application using an open source product, preferred Leaflet (but I will Switch the product if it works within another Framework than leaflet), simply showing a base map and with the possibility that the user can load (through a search on the computer system) raster images that only have to be displayed.

What is the basic conceputal Approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading the reference for [`L.ImageOverlay`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#imageoverlay), and [browse plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers) such as `L.ImageOverlay.Rotated` and `L.DistortableImage`.